# Permutacion sin repeticiones

Tags: vb.net

Tengo lo siguiente que, lo que hace es escribir combinaciones de unos caracteres especificados. Pero al acabar encuentro que todas las combinaciones dadas están repetidas.
Lo que intento es cambiar el código para que no se repita ninguna. Pero es bastante complicado para mi.

```html
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Tbx2.MaxLength = 9
        Rtb2.Clear()
        Dim prmttn = (Permutation.Create(Tbx2.Text, sort:=False))
        Rtb2.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, prmttn)
        Lbl2.Text = FormatNumber(Rtb2.Lines.Count, 0)
End Sub
Public NotInheritable Class Permutation
        Public Shared Function Create(array As Char()) As List(Of String)
            Return Create(array, False)
        End Function
        Public Shared Function Create(array As Char(), sort As Boolean) As List(Of String)
            If array Is Nothing Then
                Throw New ArgumentNullException("array")
            ElseIf (array.Length < 0) OrElse (array.Length > 9) Then
                Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("array")
            End If
            Dim list As New List(Of String)
            Dim n As Integer = array.Length
            Permute(list, array, 0, array.Length)
            If sort Then
                list.Sort()
            End If
            Return list
        End Function
        Private Shared Sub Permute(list As List(Of String), array As Char(), start As Integer, n As Integer)
            Print(list, array, n)
            If start < n Then
                Dim i, j As Integer
                For i = n - 2 To start Step -1
                    For j = i + 1 To n - 1
                        Swap(array, i, j)
                        Permute(list, array, i + 1, n)
                    Next
                    RotateLeft(array, i, n)
                Next
            End If
        End Sub
        Private Shared Sub Print(list As List(Of String), array As Char(), size As Integer)
            If array.Length <> 0 Then
                Dim s As Char() = New Char(size - 1) {}
                For i As Integer = 0 To size - 1
                    s(i) = array(i)
                Next
                
                list.Add(s)

            End If
        End Sub
        Private Shared Sub RotateLeft(array As Char(), start As Integer, n As Integer)
            Dim tmp As Char = array(start)
            For i As Integer = start To n - 2
                array(i) = array(i + 1)
            Next
            array(n - 1) = tmp
        End Sub
        Private Shared Sub Swap(array As Char(), i As Integer, j As Integer)
            Dim tmp As Char
            tmp = array(i)
            array(i) = array(j)
            array(j) = tmp
        End Sub
    End Class
        'Resultado
        'ASA
        'AAS
        'SAA
        'SAA
        'AAS
        'ASA
```

cambiado   list.Add(s) por:
If Not list.Contains(array) Then list.Add(s) 
ahora va demasiado lento y no me interesa

```html
        Private Shared Sub Print(list As List(Of String), array As Char(), size As Integer)
            If array.Length <> 0 Then
                Dim s As Char() = New Char(size - 1) {}
                For i As Integer = 0 To size - 1
                    s(i) = array(i)
                Next

                ''list.Add(s) por:
                If Not list.Contains(array) Then list.Add(s) 
           
            End If
        End Sub
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Lo primero es que "No se repiten", si lo menciona por la combinación ASA, esto sucede porque la vocal A esta dos veces, la primera vez que aparece A-1 esta en la posición 0 y A-2 esta en la posición 2, en la segunda véz que aparece A-2 esta en la pocision 0 y A-1 esta en la posición 2. Ahora, para que la segunda ASA no aparezca, cada combinación calculada deberia ser guardada en una colección tipo `SET`donde no se admiten repeticiones, al final recorre la colección e imprime todas las cadenas calculadas.

Comment: Comprendo que se repiten porque hay varias. Pero no se como arreglarlo para que no pase. Agradecería ayuda para:          -cada combinación calculada deberia ser guardada en una colección tipo SETdonde no se admiten repeticiones, al final recorre la colección e imprime todas las cadenas calculadas

Comment: En el evento
        Private Sub Print(list As List(Of String), array As Char(), size As Integer)
        He cambiado - list.Add(s)
        por
  -- If Not list.Contains(array) Then list.Add(s) --
                          
Pero ahora para secuencias de 9 caracteres se torna muy lento (demasiado). Ero sin el cambio hecho por mi, con una secuencia de 9 caracteres, no tarda 3 segundos para un resultado de 362.880 combinaciones.

Comment: Lo que he hecho es, a falta de algo mejor, añadir después de la línea Nº5, en el evento Button2_Click, la línea Nº6 "Rtb2.Lines = Rtb2.Lines.Distinct.ToArray". Para eliminar todas las repetidas.